# Convert back from https to http

Tags: http, https, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I use `force_ssl` to force a controller to use https. But when I keep navigating the site, it's now always in `https`. How can I tell Rails only to use `https` for specific controllers and `http` for others?

Answer (score 0):

You should really be doing this in your `.htaccess` file, not in your application code.

Something like:

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(projects|sign-in|user)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
```